# Combining data from multiple continuous rasters in ArcGIS

Tags: python, arcpy, raster

I am new to using rasters and have encountered a scenario for which there is hopefully an easy solution.

I have 4 different continuous rasters that each represent the density of different habitats within a specified area (created through a FocalStatistics analysis). All 4 rasters have identical extents.

I need to use the values from these 4 different raster layers in the calculation of a Mahalanobis distance for a new output raster. Essentially, I need all 4 values for each pixel in the raster to complete the Mahalanobis calculation for each pixel.

I cannot figure out how to 'combine' the data values for the 4 different continuous rasters. I tried "Combine", but (being that they are all continuous-data rasters) I exceed the maximum size.

Is there a Map Algebra (or any other) method to parse together the 4 rasters? I can do this in R using data.table package, e.g.,

```
den_ras <- raster('denning.tif')
branch_ras <- raster('branch.tif')
cavity_ras <- raster('cavity.tif')
CWD_ras <- raster('CWD.tif')

new_raster <- data.table(denning = den_ras[], branch = branch_ras[], cavity = cavity_ras[], CWD = CWD_ras[])
```

and then running the Mahalanobis distance calculation on this new_raster.

Is there a way to do this in Python and ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a raster stack, representing a single raster object with *n* bands, not to combine the data which would result in a single raster. I believe that you can do this in Esri software using Composite Bands under Data Management.

I have no idea how you are planing on deriving a Mahalanobis distance based on the 4 values at each pixel. Functionally, you need to access a vector of values for each pixel and apply something like `mahalanobis(x, mean(x), cov(x))`. I imagine that this can be done using NumPy but, this is up to you to figure out or ask another question to find guidance. In R you could access pixel-level vectors using `terra::app`, applying the `stats::mahalanobis` function then derive the p-value using `stats::pchisq(m, df=4-1, lower.tail=FALSE)`. I am sure there is something analogous in Python but, not directly in ArcGIS or ArcGIS Pro.